# GPS not working (GPS antenna already replaced)

Tags: iphone, gps

I have an iPhone 7. My GPS shows the correct position when I'm not moving. If I use it while driving in my car, it stays at the last determined position or shows me a position inaccurate by some kilometers. I already replaced my GPS/WIFI antenna module, did a complete reset and upgraded to newest iOS version. The problem is the same for both Google Maps and Apple Maps (which I both reinstalled). Do you have any idea what the problem might be, as it does not seem to stem from antenna malfunction.

PS: I do not have any protective case or anything else that could interfere

Comment: Does it only fail to update while the phone is in the car, or also when you go for a walk/hike?

Comment: Do you have a cellular connection with data when you are driving?

Comment: @nohillside: When I'm walking/hiking it works fine.

Comment: @jksoegaard: Yes I do.

Comment: Makes me wonder whether you place it in the wrong spot in your car or whether your car is just good at blocking/dampening GPS signals...

Comment: @nohillside: It worked fine with my iPhone 6 before in the same spot in the same car. My brothers iPhone 8, 9 and 12 all work too without issues (same car). Could there be a faulty software-component or another module (on mainboard) that could cause such behavior (as antenna module is new as mentioned)?